# Best way to pass a SQL query other than a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am working on a C# console application which runs two SQL queries which are passed as strings as follows

```
private DataTable GetData(string resultsQuery) {
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(resultsQuery, sqlcon);
    DataTable dtlist = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter dalist = new SqlDataAdapter();

    dalist.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
    dalist.Fill(dtlist);
    sqlcon.Close();
    return dtlist;
}
```

but the thing is these queries keep changing very frequently and everytime they change, I have re-build, re-publish and uninstall the older application before installing the updated application which I think is a bad practice. The reason I cannot use a stored procedure is that I have only read access to the database and I cannot create a stored procedure.

**Can anyone suggest me a better way and best practice to deal with this?**

Comment: I don't understand the re-build part. Why do you need re-build when your query changed? It types changing as `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Comment: What about keeping the queries in some outside resource like an xml file (encrypted, if need to be)?

Comment: I would have said your only remaining options are 1) Read them externally from a file/registry/website or 2) Write some really smart code that figures out why/how they've changed and just produces the correct query

Comment: @DGibbs He said; _The reason I cannot use a stored procedure is that I have only read access to the database and I cannot create a stored procedure_ :)

Comment: @SonerGönül I assume he has the query string hard coded somewhere in his source

Comment: Why do the queries keep changing?   What is driving the changes?

Comment: @JamesBarrass. Yes, I have them hard coded inside my source and about the changes, that comes from the requirements and there is no pattern for changes

Comment: I'll second Zohar Peled. If you need to change the queries but don't want to keep re-building, re-publishing, they have to be able to be changed outside of the application. Normally the Database is the best place - but you can't do that here. So, an external file (like xml) that the app would point to would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, your query is part of your program's configuration, which is currently hard-coded. Therefore, a solution you need has little to do with accessing databases: you need a way to upgrade configuration settings of an installed application.

Although having a stored procedure would be a fine choice, there are other ways of achieving the effect that you are looking for:

One approach would be to configure a separate database to which you have a write access, and use it as your source of query strings. Make a table that "maps" query names to query content:

```
QueryKey Query
-------- --------------------------------------
query1   SELECT A, B, C FROM MyTable1 WHERE ...
queryX   SELECT X, Y, Z FROM MyTable2 WHERE ...
```

Your program can read this other DB at startup, and store queries for use at runtime. When end-users request their data, your program would execute the query it got from the configuration database against your read-only database.

You can take other approaches to distributing this piece of configuration. Alternatives include storing the strings in a shared folder on a file server to which your application has visibility, setting up a network service of your own to feed your application its queries at start-up, or using built-in means of configuration available in .NET. The last approach requires you to change the settings on individual machines one-by-one, which may not be an ideal roll-out scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using an external XML file was mentioned, but because this is .Net, that is exactly what the App.Config files are designed to do. There is a whole class library designed to allow you to store info in the App.Config file so it can be easily modified without recompiling the program. The big caveat is, that if the query returns an entirely different shaped result set, this will not help much. But if all you are changing is the WHERE condition or something like that, but not the SELECT list; then this approach will work fine.